# Type for "every possible string value except ..."

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to define a type that may have every string-value assigned except a few specified ones? I would like to express something along the lines of this (non-compiling) example:

```
type ReservedNames = "this" | "that"
type FooName = string - ReservedNames;
const f1 : FooName = "This" // Works
const f2 : FooName = "this" // Should error
```

Comment: No way to do this I'm afraid generally. We can create a function that will cause an error if you pass in the constant strings in  `ReservedNames` if it helps ..

Comment: By "cause an error" you mean a runtime exception? I have that in place already, I was hoping I could introduce some way to not re-check it in every `public` function that takes such a string.

Comment: No, I mean a compile time error. But only if the constant is passed in. I can add it as an answer if you are intrested

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This isn't currently possible in TypeScript, however you can create a generic type that can handle many of the practical use cases if you add the concrete string value as a parameter of `FooName`.

```
type ReservedNames = "this" | "that"
type NotA<T> = T extends ReservedNames ? never : T
type NotB<T> = ReservedNames extends T ? never : T
type FooName<T> = NotA<T> & NotB<T>

const f1: FooName<'This'> = 'This' // works
const f2: FooName<'this'> = 'this' // error

const f3: FooName<string> = 'this' //error
const f4: FooName<any> = 'this' // error
const f5: FooName<unknown> = 'this' // error
```

And in a function it works as expected if you make the function generic on the string value:

```
function foo<T extends string> (v: FooName<T>) {
  ...
}

foo('this') // error
foo('This') // works
```

Comment: I found this solution more helpful than the accepted one, thank you @ccarton.

Comment: To be clear: f3, f4, and f5 all fail on any assignment...  f3: FooName<string> = 'hello';
Not sure if this is as expected by OP, but I was hoping for something that would allow all strings except the reserved words.

Comment: @Larry For direct assingments you use `f: FooName<'hello'> = 'hello'`. And everywhere else use generically as `FooName<T>`

Comment: Not quite. I am looking for a single type that matches all strings, except for some set. There some work being done to make this possible (see Negated Types: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317)

Unfortunately, the answer you gave here doesn't do this. See this playground link: shorturl.at/kACV8

Comment: @Larry, true that it's not the precise type that you are asking for, however it does solve most practical use cases that people have when looking for such a type. Here are two variations on your sample which work: https://codesandbox.io/s/e49o4?file=/index.ts

Comment: This doesn't help for the case of needing to make some "special" keys in an otherwise open-ended map/object, does it?
e.g. `type SomeOptions = { name: string; /* special key */, [key: string]: MyOptionType; /* every other property is this type */ }`

Comment: @jacobq you can do that with a simple intersection: `type SomeOptions = { name: string } & Record<string, MyOptionType>`

Comment: @ccarton while I can declare that type, I can't seem to actually use it. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyZgEsD2A7AKuaBeKA3gLABQUUAZqqgFxQBG1ANhAIboDcpAvqaJFADKqALYREKDAGco+AlHSsxAfjpTgAJ2ToA5lG5QAZFABKEAMaoNAEwA86rboA0sBEjRYcAPi4lSl9HUoVHdpWUJScnJFMToAcnpWDTinSKiQ4ABGOnkqWihNAFcIF25UkgNWGWExCQ8pX39pVBYAOiZUHQAKDPqASg4gA

Comment: @jacobq Ah, right, my bad. That is more complicated than I thought. Maybe you could use something like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyZgEsD2A7AKuaBeKA3gLABQUUAZqqgFxQBG1ANhAIboDcpAvqaaJCgBlVAFsIiFBgDOAHkwA+KPmJko6VuID8dacABOydAHMeUAGSFS5ANoBrKEagBRAB4BjJgFcAJhFl2ECCoFFCYADRQAOQa4lEKALp0cJJoWDg8fCTuMsBQAJLoFBD6AILSIuKpMspQ8lAQrsAQ6D7SwmISSGlyigoAFABuNJgAlMpKg1BZOeh6UKjdNfiFxWUVndVz-ark5LEQdFH0rPpR4dZ7BwBMR6zSPhTnl+SLwACMdASU1HQGXhBItwLiRuKMZrkFks5tdaqsSuVKl0pNtdldNIdoicziC9lCPl8oK4-voAUCQWCIXM8m8egBmOFFBEbKrQ6Q7F7qDFHbHPNSvJCfQg-WhQf6AqDAnjgkhAA

Answer (score 40):

There isn't a general solution to this problem since there is no way to express in the typescript type system the fact that a string can be any value except a list. (One might think the conditional type `Exclude<string, ReservedNames>` would work but it does not, **it just evaluates back to string**).

As a work around, if we have a function and we specifically want to not allow certain constants to be passed in we can us a conditional type to check for `ReservedNames` and, if the passed in parameter is `ReservedNames` then type the input parameter in such a way it is effectively impossible to satisfy (using an intersection type).

```
type ReservedNames = "this" | "that"
type FooName = Exclude<string, ReservedNames>;
const f1 : FooName = "This" // Works
const f2 : FooName = "this" // One might expect this to work but IT DOES NOT as FooName is just evaluates to string


function withName<T extends string>(v: T & (T extends ReservedNames ? "Value is reserved!": {})) {
  return v;
}

withName("this"); // Type '"this"' is not assignable to type '"Value is reserved!"'.
withName("This") // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOEBOA3CATAcgQwLYKgF4oAiYACwEt4SoAfUi7YEgKFEigDEB7HnfESgBRAB4BjADYBXdBAA88YEkoA7AOYAaWAmRoseBAD4A3K3E9VSqADMAjFABc3PgOjESAFSo0oAej8oAHUeJABreHNLaxsAJicXfkMhMh9aAKgAeVVoXEp1cmAoCFFIcSKKaihgHigAd1CwqAAjaSKASU8oABFM4QBlKExMrux4RLcoKoAraWsIFGwZZgIaqCUVDVZtm2lVcspLesoKN3kukuAIVXRxjbV1IwAKFGcugDIoJ4vRK5vxuCIVAYNzjAD8pAAaktpNAqkhdMD0ABCEjOADeAF8AJTYqDo1hQKAI4DSJCqKAoMyY7Z1E7kNxPVLUEjYkz+QKecDQADkzJoPKm41UPCKY3g+VU2Gakmgaw4vJI0JkcPGCKB+lRPIAdKw6adDEzvCy8RkeGEgA)

Comment: Perhaps this worked at one point, but no longer: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOEBOA3CATAcgQwLYKgF4oAiYACwEt4SoAfUi7YEgKFEigDEB7HnfESgBRAB4BjADYBXdBAA88YEkoA7AOYAaWAmRoseBAD4A3K3E9VSqADMAjFABc3PgOjESAFSo0oAej8oAHUeJABreHNLaxsAJicXfkMhMh9aAKgAZXIeaUl0KGQkUKA

Comment: @maxedison I think I make it clear in the answer that the `Exclude` with a  variable approach does not work (never has, might work when negated types come along). The part that works is the function approach. Made this more explicit, sorry for the confusion. Also added a playground link 

Comment: The above example works great, in the end I used `T & (T extends ReservedNames ? never : T)`. Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 1):

A warning:

I wanted this for some react components that I wanted to take some string-valued prop keys that should be anything but a set of localization system lookup constants, and while the [accepted answer from ccarton above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51445345/1130377) does the trick (applied here, too: [Playgrounds](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQduEAdqvDFMqwDbIzAt0AXjgBvOnEnlg3blgDmybmQBc5CP1kBTmFmZkANBKlkC0AEbAAJlb2ryBAG9RzAKwCut-XQC%20KdEysMPR0MACeYFhwADIQuAAiwPhwIuGREARwHFyovPyC9GlRsbgA0lhhKXAA1hUZMXGJ%20IURxXEAyhzAzPJVJU0wANol5WEAujRwAPRTcGxQSbpQcIHzyN3sABZccAByGiMVDEV7GgCCADwAKgB8VVdwWAAeusxW6IeVAPxwzFgAblhlmori1IqcYAAha53ESfR4vPTvOAPH5-QHAlH0Z6QWBZVoQz4wqr7GCXW5wABkEOhtxCBHczHwAmYcHiWBAXHe%202Yn1Q1wRr2R8268huAApRFlgDA5AYss94D41OIpNLZVg1KSibcjGrdC8vlqDnFRjDfABKMTGSSUGDuKCsi43UQGmDKsT8DU%20C5TG70HwhC7szlvVA8vnquRCURkGRyRTKPxumNkACEZB8fsmapmcAI624qHlaDgAHcuLorHBAHwbgAJdujBjlc8MsSNe6Ox5gaTMKl6pswuaxeTPZ6azAsyYv%20cuVrDV%20uNkMtiOmiroDtYVNcMIwTai3sp2PyCBYVCj-3jlCyX4sAC0nzUEGqaboQA)), it is also worth mentioning that typescript's error messages when your code fails to meet the type constraint, are *completely rubbish*, and actively misleading – example from the playground link / code below:

```
<DemandsNonLocKeys title={"illegal"} text={"!"}/>; // fails, as wanted
```

Hover the marked-as-illegal `title` attribute's squigglies (yes, not `text`), and you currently (* with typescript 4.7.2, in case this ever improves in some direction) see:

```
(property) title: "!"
Type '"illegal"' is not assignable to type '"!"'.(2322)
```

So, while this hack is excellent for things like preventing commit hooks from committing buggy code, it relies on developers to have tribal knowledge about what is wrong when these errors strike, as the error message is completely off the rails.

Complete example code, in case Playgrounds ever dies:

```
import * as React from "react";

const translations = {
    "illegal": "otillåten",
    "forbidden": "förbjuden"
} as const;

type LocDict = typeof translations;
type LocKey = keyof LocDict;
type LocString = LocDict[LocKey]; // stricter constraint than NotLocKey

type NotA<T> = T extends LocKey ? never : T;
type NotB<T> = LocKey extends T ? never : T;
export type NotLocKey<T> = NotA<T> & NotB<T>;

function DemandsNonLocKeys<T extends string>({ title, text }: {
    title: NotLocKey<T>,
    text?: NotLocKey<T>
}) {
    return <>{text}: {title}</>;
};

<DemandsNonLocKeys title={"illegal"} text={"!"}/>;     // fails, as wanted 
<DemandsNonLocKeys title={"not"} text={"forbidden"}/>; // fails, as wanted 
<DemandsNonLocKeys title={"anything"} text={"goes"}/>; // all non-LocKey: ok!
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Doh. I need to stop skimming text... my answer does not solve OP's problem. Trying it with `type FooName = keyof RestrictedRecord` does **not** work. I'll leave my answer instead of deleting FWIW.

Original post:

this seems to work for me (typescript v5.3.2), but only very slightly improves the vague errors. but it seems more readable/maintainable to me:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgU2nAlsKCAmBpBBPCGAXhgG0ByKACxQnIBoZKqBDKcgXRhcNEigDcAKCh4ADghgAlJFFTosuPMRiiJIAGbxZ8jDnwRSYAK4BbAEYI4HYSPGSZyNHpmg4mFa5DuAPE7AA5oz%20AQB8MABkMAAKLHBQKCwANj5evo5yzor4jGAIAG5WoaG2fNAwASAgmACMAFzSOlmYaR4kAN5UCElJIA3kAO7eSZjkAL7CZbDmLLUNGbpYrSrt1Gz9Q3Aj45Pg5TOYAEzzTQotCG5tMKusUA3GYJgIGih5mBNCQgD0XzAAKiAYEkEHEwDBTN5JCxzCBjLBqJIkixAsYWAEEIxgEk0ABrbgwwowV4wABEAFEAB4sUxiYEQEkwbykgDqt3IhAAcggBiSAHTfX4AeQRcAGtAxFQQsGgcT0MHMykQEPyrwCqi6EEkoFMpgQYCghGRHgRME2IyJhDwsLgMFpLDwATgsMe-JgMCAA)

```
const restrictedKeys = ['this', 'that'] as const;
type RestrictedKey = typeof restrictedKeys[number];

// i'd wager order is important here with restricted coming second, but i didn't confirm
type RestrictedRecord = Record<string, string> & Partial<Record<RestrictedKey, never>>;

const good1: RestrictedRecord = {hello: 'world'}; // ok
const bad1: RestrictedRecord = {that: 'world'}; // error is "that" must be undefined
const bad2: RestrictedRecord = {that: undefined}; // error is "that" must be string, but at least mentions the RestrictedRecord type
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved this with the following, which:

1. Creates an object whose keys are `Literals`, which is a union of literals.
2. Omits from the object any literals in type `ExcludedLiterals` which is a subset of `Literals`.
3. Returns the `keyof` resolution of the object.

```
type OmitLiteral<Literals extends string | number, ExcludedLiterals extends Literals> = keyof Omit<{ [Key in Literals]: never }, ExcludedLiterals>;
```

It's a bit convoluted, but it works.

```
type BaseUnion = "abc" | "def" | "ghi"; // "abc" | "def" | "ghi"
type OmittedUnion = OmitLiteral<BaseUnion, "ghi">; // "abc" | "def"
```

Comment: `Exclude<BaseUnion, "ghi">` gets exactly the same result. This also does not answer the question, which is asking to exclude one string from all possible strings.