# Typescript: type is any string except for a few exceptions

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in typescript to define a type which accepts anything except for a few things?

Consider this snippet:

```
type BagGuys = 'Voldemort' | 'Hitler';

type EveryoneElse = Exclude<string, BagGuys>; // this resolves to just string

function sayHi(name: EveryoneElse) {
  console.log(`Hi ${name}!`);
}

sayHi('Mark'); // Ok!

sayHi('Voldemort'); // Ok too, we'd like to have an error here
```

I, of course, would like typescript to prevent me from saying hi to the bad guys.

Note: I understand why `Exclude` doesn't work here, I'm just using it to convey my intention

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type for "every possible string value except ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442157/type-for-every-possible-string-value-except)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
type BagGuys = 'Voldemort' | 'Hitler';


function sayHi<T extends string>(name: T extends BagGuys ? never : T) {
  console.log(`Hi ${name}!`);
}

sayHi('Mark'); // Ok
sayHi('Voldemort'); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Playground here.

I think this is as good as we can get until [negated types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) is implemented. Feel free to upvote that PR btw :)

**Note:** I came up with this inspired by [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442157/type-for-every-possible-string-value-except).

**Note 2**: for some reason, if I type the function with `sayHi<T>` instead of `sayHi<T extends string>`, this doesn't work. I guess it's a question for a different day.