# TypeScript: non-zero number

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to set up a type in TypeScript that reflects a non-zero number:

```
type Task = { id: number };
const task: Task = { id: 5 };
const tasks: { [taskId: number]: Task } = { 5: task };

function getTask(taskId: number | undefined): Task | undefined {
    return taskId && tasks[taskId];
}
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgZwNZQLxQN5QJYBMBcUAdgK4C2ARhAE5QC%20A3AFADGA9kQsFMIkofGRpMOAlACs9Zu07deyBISwBteUgCSY0pRoBdAX3rCs4wmqlMmAMxJEWwbBygBzCMEFIAFGs2FtVWgAfKFtcCCtsIghcAEoDIWDQ8MjozCYoDKhqNxJqIh4%20TSgAMmKChVVC3F1mOiA)

In the above code, TypeScript complains that because `taskId` is a number, it could be `0`, which is falsey, so the function would return `0` rather than a `Task` or `undefined`. Practically speaking, it is impossible for a task id to be `0`. It will always be a positive integer, so that case is not an issue. Is there a way to declare the `Task` type to indicate to TypeScript that this number will never be falsey? I'd rather avoid extra conditional logic to convince TypeScript.

Comment: why don't you use a simple array instead of a hashmap, whose keys are numbers?

Comment: No, not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442157/type-for-every-possible-string-value-except. But you could use overloads to solve this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgZwNZQLxQN5QJYBMBcUAdgK4C2ARhAE5QC+A3AFADGA9kQsFMIkofGRpMOAlACs9Zu07deyBISwBteUgCSY0pRoBdAX3rCs4wmqlMmAMxJEWwbBygBzCMEFIAFGs2EADACUhEQQAG401rb2jkQubh7efL5QtrgQVtghuEEpRGkZWZF2Dk6u7nyJyMnaVNQ5HkXRpfEVPrgA-MHktQGYTFADUNRuJNSxbVAAZJM8fAiqSbi6zHSWMlw8fsJlCYGsHBvAAKp56ZkQuNstyJ6pZ1kB+7I8AIxX5TcvgUA

Comment: Another option: `return taskId && tasks[taskId] || undefined;`

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for typescript to guarantee that there will be a task for any possible `taskId`.

There are a few options here:

- use the non null assertion operator to inform typescript that you know better and are sure the task will always exist
- constrain the type to be the set of possible `taskId` by defining them as an enum or similar
- check that the task exists and throw an exception if it is undefined

Assuming that your set of tasks is dynamic, I would personally go for the last option, eg:

```
function getTask(taskId: number): Task {
     const task = tasks[taskId]
     
     if(!task){ throw new Error(`task with id ${taskId} does not exist`) }

    return task
}
```

As this will give you a useful error if your invariant is violated.

Comment: The question here isn't whether there is a task, but whether the `taskId` will be `0`. `taskId` might be `undefined` or there might not be a task, which is fine, but I'm trying to convince TypeScript that it won't be `0`, which is falsey.