# TypeScript: typing a plugins array (similar to Babel/ESLint configs)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a system similar to ESLint / Babel where there are plugins with options expressed as `[string,object]`

For a small list of official plugins, where types are known, I'd like to provide type-checking, and an autocompletion IDE experience.

I'm not sure how to implement this.

```
type OfficialPluginsToOptions = {
    "plugin-1": {
        option1: string,
    }
    "plugin-2": {
        option2: boolean,
    }
}

type PluginConfig = [string,object] |
    ["plugin-1",OfficialPluginsToOptions["plugin-1"]] |
    ["plugin-2",OfficialPluginsToOptions["plugin-2"]]

type Config = {
    plugins: PluginConfig[];
}

const config: Config = {
    plugins: [
        [
            "plugin-1",
            {option1: 42} // This should fail + IDE autocompletion should work
        ],
        [
            "plugin-1",
            {option2: 42} // This should fail + IDE autocompletion should work
        ],
        [
            "custom-user-plugin",
            {whatever: "anything"} // This should accept any option
        ],
    ]
}
```

Somehow I'd like to have my larger type to be reduced to `[string - officialPluginName,object]`

This seems related to this question, but couldn't make anything work:
[Type for "every possible string value except ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442157/type-for-every-possible-string-value-except)

Anyone can help?

Open to any suggestion.

If it's also possible to type the user-provided plugins, that would be awesome (the config file is written in js with a JSDoc annotation, users are not particularly familiar with TS)