# Prohibit calling a function with 0 by overloading with void/never

Tags: typescript

This is valid code in typescript

```
function foo(arg: 0): never
function foo(arg: number): number {
  if (arg === 0) throw "..."
  
  return arg
}

let a: number
a = foo(0)
```

Or, I could overload with void instead of never

```
function foo(arg: 0): void
```

My goal is to prevent someone from calling this function with 0 for `arg`, since this will throw an error.

Questions:

- Why is it acceptable to overload a function with `void` when the implementation doesn't include `void`?
- If I do only the void overload, typescript recognizes an error in the last line, because `a` should be a number and `foo(0)` returns void. However, there is no error when I do the `never` overload, its acceptable according to typescript. Why?

Comment: Because never is for functions that don't ever return, either they throw or loop indefinitely, so the type of the value it will never return doesn't really matter. Void is for functions that do return and return undefined, which isn't a number.

Comment: So my idea is, since my function divides by the argument, it cannot be zero and I'm just trying to represent this in an overload. Thats why I figured to overload with never. But this doesn't prevent wrong function calls because never will still be accepted by properties expecting a number. That's what doesn't really make sense to me. Is there no way to warn someone calling this function with 0?

Comment: There are so many things going on in this small bit of code  that I will end up writing a book if I answer it:  A `void` return type means "don't look at what this returns" and not "this will not return anything".  ​Överløads are resolved at call sites and the first matching call signature is what is used; since `(arg: 0) => never` and `(arg: 0) => void` have exactly the same arguments, the second call signature will always be ignored at call sites, so it is bizarre to do this.

Comment: @boy ah, so this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  You want to make a function that prohibits being called with `0`.  Is *that* the real question?  If so, please consider editing the question to highlight this.  It's fine to say "I want to do X, and I tried to do Y and it didn't work; how do I do X?"  But saying "What is going on with Y?" without reference to X is going to give you long answers about Y when you don't even really care.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest to use both overloads, rather I'm comparing the overloads, maybe I shuold clarify that.

Comment: @boy - With your edit, you no longer have an overloaded function. The implementation signature isn't included in the list of overloads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type for "every possible string value except ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442157/type-for-every-possible-string-value-except)

Comment: This depends strongly on use cases, I think.  You could do [either of these](https://tsplay.dev/WkvvLm) but the call signatures are fairly complicated.  The problem is that if you try to call the function with a value the compiler doesn't know for sure is *not* `0`, what do you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: How can I prohibit someone from passing `0` in as a function argument?

Answer: Well, uh, it's not pretty.

There are [numeric literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#numeric-literal-types), so you can refer to the type `0` to talk about the number whose value is `0`.  But TypeScript currently *lacks* [negated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317), so there's no straightforward way to say `not 0` meaning "everything except `0`".  If it did, you'd make `arg` of type `number & not 0`.  Since there is no such type, you'll need to give up on using a specific type and instead have to use some other functionality.

---

[Overloads with multiple call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) *might* be pressed into service here, but not in a straightforward way.  It's easy to make a call signature that accepts *only* `0`, but actually *prohibiting* `0` is a different story.  And even if you could do that, you'd need another call signature that accepts `number`, and if you do *that*, someone could send a `0` to your function by widening it to `number`:

```
const zero = 0; // const zero: 0
const zilch = 1 - 1; //const zilch: number
```

In the above, `zero` is known by the compiler to be `0`, but `zilch` is not.  The compiler doesn't do math at compile time ([mostly, anyway](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#computed-and-constant-members)).  So you'd be worrying about how to make something like `number & not 0` and you're back to where you started.

---

Instead I'd suggest going one of two routes, both of which use [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) functions and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) to tease apart the difference between `0` and non-`0` inputs:

---

The first one actually *prohibits* `0`:

```
function prohibitZero<T extends (0 extends T ? never : number)>(arg: T): number {
    if (arg === 0) throw new Error("uh oh");
    return 1 / arg; 
}
prohibitZero(10); // okay
prohibitZero(0); // error
prohibitZero(Math.random()); // error! number is possibly 0
prohibitZero(1 + 1); // error!  'number', not '2': the compiler doesn't do math like this
```

In the above, the generic type `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) by the conditional type so that `0 extends T` cannot be true.  If it is possible to assign `0` to `arg`, the compiler will complain.  This allows calling `prohibitZero()` with any nonzero numeric literal type like `10`.  But it's actually pretty hard to use, since most of the time you will expect `number` to come in.  The compiler will reject `number` because `0 extends number`.  And so an argument like `1 + 1` fails.

---

The second one just *checks* for `0`:

```
function checkZero<T extends number>(
  arg: T
): T extends 0 ? undefined : number extends T ? number | undefined : number;
function checkZero(arg: number): number | undefined {
    if (arg === 0) return undefined;
    return 1 / arg;
}
checkZero(10); // number
checkZero(0); // undefined
checkZero(Math.random()) // number | undefined
checkZero(1 + 1) // number | undefined
```

The generic type `T` is constrained only to `number` and will allow any numeric input.  The return type though tries to figure out whether or not `0` was passed in, and return `undefined` if so.  `checkZero(10)` returns `number` because there's no overlap between `10` and `0`.  `checkZero(0)` returns `undefined` because it's definitely `0`.  And for any `number`, `checkZero()` returns `number | undefined` because it *may or may not* be `0`.

---

There are possibly other approaches, but they all suffer from the same issue with lack of true negated types, and the fact that the compiler cannot in general know whether or not  a `number` is `0`.  So you should consider whether prohibiting `0` like this is worth the complexity and effort.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAXgUwE4hgXhgBgNwwPR4yiSyIoBcWAUMdPAJYA2wAFujAIwwC0nuBtUk1aUwAVwC2AI2RU5AMzFhgUeuBgAHFC3pT6UAFrIQAHgAqMBAA8oCMABMIMABSZLNu45gWA-DDAIAG7IMKKSMkgAlAB8zgCGSADmlGaRYdIhAN5UMLkw9PIuCYnoaBiYkTBQLCgA7v4I9QCiSChIzgBEYmwgLB2R2Dl5SAhQYkhgnPgwxbhUAL5UWr26+kYozhwV-IQgANZxAJ5L2quGxq4D+ITIbScreucbALJx1QB0SHEOIBLOkVcCJZWiAkABCfzhEL0JwaEAQCC6RiHajLHSPdYgTYwADUnEBNxB4KmeK4MJgIEKUEOGgQMAA5OIMkh6QAafwgWD0gBMbJgMmAcTEEDp1TpoAkGiYIXsIAQEDA9NgspgEjebEY9D2op0EDkVEUylU6lYCGAe0x5nctgcTiZEVixRSaW81s8TjcfiU9gQ8noAXsoUhzLdttdfntIQAPjBvb7-QhA+kIoNDSo1JNTebMfEksnkC7I0gYDG436AzBsnl8oVcyUyuVKiMxhNYw54wHBtXm+NJlxCLMFjQWGaLRctgTgxFh6Oc9trm2feXEzPsxdXh8vj8-gCF0WS4uOyus2ONlxSZUgfvS+3l-YgA)