# How can i define a string type 'not in' a union in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If there is a type:

```js
type Text1 = "a" | "b";
```

So, how to define a string that not in `Text1`? Similar to the following：

```
type Text2 = Exclude<string, Text1>;

// I hope to get an error here, but not
const a: Text2 = "a";
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215950/exclude-property-from-type?

Comment: Please see the linked question, namely [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51445345/1470607) by Titian Cernicova-Dragomir.