# Conditional properties and switch statements in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I defined these types:

```js
type ItemWithName = {
  type: "ItemWithName";
  name: string;
  a: { name: string } ;
};

type ItemWithValue = {
  type: string;
  name: string;
  b: { value: number } ;
};

export type Item = ItemWithName | ItemWithValue;
```

And I have a function to extract a certain value from an object:

```js
const extractValue = (item: Item) => {
  switch (item.type) {
    case "ItemWithName":
      return item.a.name; // TS2339: Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Item'.
    case "ItemWithValue":
      return item.b.value; 
  }
};
```

But I get this error: `TS2339: Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Item'.`

I'm not entirely sure how to make TypeScript understand that if the type of the object is "ItemWithValue", there's a property a.

Note: this is a small abstraction of my particular issue, in reality I have several more of these types.

The expected behaviour is that TypeScript detects that the item is of type `ItemWithName` if the object has a type value of `"ItemWithName"`

Comment: The example you gave above has no issues. Can you look into it again?

Comment: Just looked into it and updated the question. One of the types (`ItemWithValue`) has a `type` property that's defined simply as a `string`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this doesn't currently work with Typescript.

[Here's an issue on GitHub about a similar problem.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729)

[type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) has a wrapper type `LiteralUnion` for the problem referenced in the issue. However you can't just use it like
`type Item = LiteralUnion<ItemWithName, ItemWithValue>`.

So these are my two possibilities at the moment:

1. Possibility: simply cast the type

```
const extractValue = (item: Item) => {
  switch (item.type) {
    case "ItemWithName":
      const itemWithName = item as ItemWithName;
      return itemWithName.a.name;
    case "ItemWithValue":
      return item.b.value; 
  }
};
```

2. Possibility: list all possible types

> Note: this is a small abstraction of my particular issue, in reality I have several more of these types.

Instead of using

```
type ItemWithValue = {
  type: string;
  name: string;
  b: { value: number } ;
};
```

you could create a type which unions all possible types like

```
type ItemWithValue = {
  type: 'ItemWithValue' | 'OtherItemWithValue' | 'AgainAnItemWithValue';
  name: string;
  b: { value: number } ;
};
```

It would be really cool to use `type: Exclude<string, 'ItemWithName'>`. But this also would not work as you can see in [this discussed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442157/type-for-every-possible-string-value-except).