# How to exclude a key in a string？

Tags: typescript-typings

How to exclude a key in a string？

like this：

```
declare interface PresetConfig {
  root?: HTMLElement
  tunneling?: boolean,
  applets?: {
    system?: SystemAppletSettings
    frameworks: FrameworksAppletSettings
    [key: Exclude<string, 'frameworks' | 'system'>]: AppletSettings | undefined
  }
}
```

but `Exclude<string, 'frameworks' | 'system'>` doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be currently impossible to exclude specific string values from the general `string` type. There's work being done on [negated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196), but it's unclear if and when that will actually make it into TypeScript (see also [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317), and a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442157/type-for-every-possible-string-value-except) for some use cases).

However, for your specific case: if `SystemAppletSettings` and `FrameworkAppletSettings` both extend `AppletSettings`, you can use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) to get what you're after:

```
interface AppletSettings {a: any};
interface SystemAppletSettings extends AppletSettings {sa: any};
interface FrameworksAppletSettings extends AppletSettings {fa: any};

declare interface PresetConfig {
  root?: HTMLElement
  tunneling?: boolean,
  applets?: {
    system?: SystemAppletSettings
    frameworks: FrameworksAppletSettings
  } & {
    [key: string]: AppletSettings
  }
}
```

Comment: I can work with intersection types, but they are shared types, and my purpose is to distinguish between types that hold keys

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: "intersection type" works though, but properties in  FrameworksAppletSettings can still work when the properties of my object are other characters of non-frameworks. So how could I distinguish that?

Comment: Maybe you need to add some more detail to your question, because I have no idea what you're asking.