# Use type checking for unique string literals in union types

Tags: typescript, string-literals, union-types

**Edited:**

Having union types like these:

```js
type SomeElements = 'element1' | 'element2';
type OtherElements = 'element3' | 'element4' | 'element1';
type MoreElements = 'element5' | 'element6';

const someElements: { [key in SomeElements]: key; } = {
  element1: 'element1',
  element2: 'element2',
};

const otherElements: { [key in OtherElements]: key; } = {
  element3: 'element3',
  element4: 'element4',
  element1: 'element1'
};

const moreElements: { [key in MoreElements]: key; } = {
    element5: "element5",
    element6: "element6",
};
```

Is it possible to use type checking to know at compile time that `allElements` contains duplicate entries to avoid having to filter the array at runtime?

```js
type Elements = SomeElements | OtherElements | MoreElements;

const allElements: Elements[] = (
  Object.values(someElements) as Elements[]
).concat(
  Object.values(otherElements)
).concat(
  Object.values(moreElements)
);

/*
allElements =
["element1", "element2", "element3", "element4", "element1", "element5", "element6"] 
*/

const removeDuplicates = (strings: Elements[]) => strings.filter(
  (value, index) => strings.indexOf(value) === index
);

const allElementsFiltered = removeDuplicates(
  (
    Object.values(someElements) as Elements[]
  ).concat(
    Object.values(otherElements)
  ).concat(
    Object.values(moreElements)
  )
);

/*
allElementsFiltered =
["element1", "element2", "element3", "element4", "element5", "element6"]
*/
```

Comment: I am not sure why you want to disallow it or get an error. Union elements are unique anyways so adding an existing element to a union won't modify it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type for "every possible string value except ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442157/type-for-every-possible-string-value-except)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have compile-time error when two unions are overlapping, you could use a type-checking function similar to [`ts-expect`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-expect).

First we define a generic type which returns `true` if two unions are not overlapping and `false` if otherwise.

```
type Union1 = 'element1' | 'element2';
type Union2 = 'element3' | 'element4';
type Union3 = 'element3' | 'element4' | 'element1';


type UniqueUnions<U1, U2> = (U1 extends U2 ? false : never) extends never ? true : false

type T0 = UniqueUnions<Union1, Union2>
//   ^? type T0 = true

type T1 = UniqueUnions<Union1, Union3>
//   ^? type T1 = false
```

Now we need a function which expects `true` as the generic type.

```
const expect = <T extends true>() => {}

expect<UniqueUnions<Union1, Union2>>() 
expect<UniqueUnions<Union1, Union3>>() // compile-time error
```

If we pass two overlapping unions, we get a compile-time error.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=61&pln=16&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwIxQLxQOQQDYQC2Ecwq2UAPjvkScAEzYDcAUKJLIig5jQcVIBmCtVwD6AFhbtw0eMjhC%204usNH81waVU2CyM1rM4KAjgFcIClAGcAPDFQAaWAwB8fABSOoEAB7AJAAmNq5QAPxQAGYAhng20ABcUHAQAG4QAE4AlL4BwaGpGZkRUMCZllDJsfEQRhzQACoADHxmltZw9p3OXIrurAD0g1CjAHqRDVAtfOWW9XLT6FjtVtxdDuu9nUJuQyPjk4uNy9FxCUZGAMa2wHmQV3dYdo15gXAhZRUQbp65GB4AN4AXyM-gewE2CAsa0U3S2Lk67l%20uVY4IgjyhMM68MU23WuxRUGGUBuhDACAIAFpgAhiL5MpkkJkgA)

Comment: Yes, this allowed me to accomplish what I wanted: [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NV4qMW)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible using [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers). Example:

```
type SomeElements = 'element1' | 'element2';
type OtherElements = 'element3' | 'element4' | 'element1'; // Disallow this 
type Elements = Exclude<SomeElements, OtherElements>;

let x: Elements;
x = "element2";
```