# How to make Typescript throw an error when assigning excess property on discriminated unions?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Let's say I have these type definitions

```
interface BaseHeaderColumn<T> {
    accessorKey: keyof T;
    label: string;
}

interface RenderableHeaderColumn<T> {
    accessorKey: string;
    label: string;
    renderCell: (originData: T) => any;
}

type HeaderColumnType<T> = BaseHeaderColumn<T> | RenderableHeaderColumn<T>;

interface DataType {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: string;
}
```

Later on, I will map the data list into a new structure like

```
const HeaderColumns: HeaderColumnType<DataType>[] = [
    {
        accessorKey: "age",
        label: "Age",
        renderCell: () => "" 
    },
    {
        accessorKey: "no",
        label: "Number",
        renderCell: (value) => "" 
    }
]
```

What I want is with the `accessorKey` is the key of T (DataType), Typescript should not allow to pass `renderCell` method to the object.
Is it possible to do this ?

I created a playground here
[TS Playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QBITgE2gGEB7AGwFcBbEAHgBUA+ZAbwChlPlEkMMSoAaQgBPAFzIA1qJIxk9ANwcuZOACMIZCRjBRQAcyUBfNm1CRYiFACUIIQlHVkceB6Uo0Gzdl24Je-EKi2roGSr6qGlrIOnoghsqcUHZumtEAFALA+qAAInBgcBL0AJTIALzMcCAixqZgIgAOKLgExOTUIPRNEF4VaJgubVDunX0APsi29tBOQ24dnkxKZuDQ8EjI+YXdzayJyCBwVBAhcQm+cPqnh9QaUOFcBPjJfGdhbCZsCCQgOsitBYeP4SQHtYG7XrbOCQxgAbQAuv04QcfL4nv4IHwBMJxMgAERXCD4gA0Bwi6k0EnxAEFrqTyVxkjMRmkJOkypUCfjkAB6XnIADKoE2PCxgVxyGAGGQvxQsmQYAAFihpCJZXJ6CTkABJZAAd2qYHkgoNwDIZEVSqgJH13BAyGgNqg3GNyulyDIoAgByMZN8aPRfgCOOCBJAJAZQc4kSpBIAcndoFHo8zUhb2QA3OCUCCc5j4nm+tgIoA)

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63549561/18377008

Comment: I don't think this would be possible without some complex generics. The issue I see is that if you pass a string for the key, TS doesn't know if it's a string or an actual key of the object since the key can be also a string. Meanwhile if your object has a number as the key, and you are passing the number, you do get the error

Comment: Thank you for all replies.
I think I might change the type of accessorKey to number instead.

Comment: It's not a discriminated union because (as mentioned above), the `accessorKey` property can be any `string`, which means the two union members overlap.  TS doesn't have negated types so you can't write `accessorKey: string & not keyof T`.  You could do something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbE4EN) if you want, I guess.  Do you want to see that written up as an answer?

Comment: @jcalz It works well as I expected so I'm pleased to mark it as an accepted answer. But could you explain the solution a little more ? It would be a great help ^^.

Comment: I will do so when I write up my answer, which will probably be after I get some sleep because it's close to my bedtime now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `HeaderColumnType<DataType>` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) but it is unfortunately *not* a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  The intended discriminant property, `accessorKey`, has the type `"name" | "age" | "address"` in the `BaseHeaderColumn<DataType>` member, and the wide type `string` in the `RenderableHeaderColumn<DataType>`.  TypeScript doesn't allow wide types like `string` to be a discriminant property type.

Even if it did, there is overlap between `"name" | "age" | "address"` and `string`, so you can't even use it to distinguish between members.  If you see `{accessorKey: "age"}`, you can't tell if it's from `"name" | "age" | "address"` or if it's from `string`.

Presumably you intended for `string` to be something like "every `string` *except* `"name" | "age" | "address"`, but since TypeScript lacks *negated types* (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) but never released), there's no type corresponding to `string & not ("name" | "age" | "address")`.

So not only can't we use a discriminated union to exactly describe the acceptable elements of `headerColumns`, we can't even use a specific type to do so.  We'll have to use something like a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type instead.

---

So we need a generic type, and we'll also want a helper function to infer the type argument (so nobody has to write it out).  Like this:

```
const asHeaderColumns = <T extends object>() => <K extends string[]>(
    ...c: { [I in keyof K]:
        { accessorKey: K[I], label: string } & (
            K[I] extends keyof T ?
            { renderCell?: never } :
            { renderCell: (originData: T) => any }
        ) }) => c;
```

So when you call `asHeaderColumns<DataType>()` you get another function like this:

```
const asHeaderColumnsDataType = asHeaderColumns<DataType>();
/* const asHeaderColumnsDataType: <K extends string[]>(
    ...c: { [I in keyof K]:
        { accessorKey: K[I], label: string } & (
            K[I] extends keyof DataType ?
            { renderCell?: never } :
            { renderCell: (originData: DataType) => any }
        ) }) => c;
*/
```

That function is generic in `K`, the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of `accessorKey` properties.  So if you call `asHeaderColumnsDataType({accessorKey: "age", ⋯}, {accessorKey: "no", ⋯})`, then `K` should be inferred as `["age", "no"]`.  Then the compiler uses this `K` to determine the `renderCell` property of each input.  If the `I`th element of `K` is a key of `DataType`, then `renderCell` should not be present... this is represented by `{renderCell?: never}`, since an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) which can only be [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) is very similar to saying it cannot be present (there's an `undefined` lurking in there, but ‍♂️).  Anyway, if the `I`th element of `K` is *not* a key of `DataType`, then `renderCell` should be a callback function that accepts a `DataType`.

Let's test it out:

```
const headerColumns = asHeaderColumns<DataType>()(
    {
        accessorKey: "age",
        label: "Age",
        renderCell: () => "" // error! 
        // Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
    },
    {
        accessorKey: "no",
        label: "Number",
        renderCell: (value) => ""
    }
);
```

Looks good.  The compiler enforces the restriction you're looking for.  It's not as nice as just having a specific type like `HeaderColumn<DataType>[]` to use, but since that's not possible, this generic helper function is the next best thing.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAQygCQKYICaoE4GEwA2ArgLbRwC8cAPACpyoAeMqEGUcYARgFaogwAfAAoAlJUE0A0g2at2cWNgCWEAOYBtALojgcfXAB0xkAC44AbzgaAknFVwA1qgCeYAGZwpW03oP+rBBAQVCgoMGwpV3MpWy0AGjgCBC5UAnMlVTU4AF84ADI4YT9-Uq842RY2Dmc3T3oAfhKygytseRxcNIIG8whUADccXLhfFtK2jrxu82EI5TVVABEEGARzWnEKSQQIF1zm-3EcrckQAG5gYFUWbHcg1DgVtdoXAAdHi2aIBBJUDJgKnUl38CDU-zgEFIqWwIIMmAw7TCAKBakuOSu4Gg8CQaEwnUIpGgzwQrw+lEQKHQWDwhLIUGoJLJqBEokuAHoAFRwLGwSl4mn4Yj0pnvCHUGRMKoKTLqbS6fzGQxmSzWOwOWoeLw+Q6tRDBULhSLRco2BJJFJpFFZEaFYrjfyxM2VeQ1Vxa0XkpoOvXtNidbq9SGDYZ5MY+1V+wUzIrzRYQEnmT2oU6IPYHcbHVMXYCc9mYyB8gAW1IJwvIVFxpdp5YZydZ9tauv0QRCYQiURc5gARGDUN34s2Lal0nBuwBBcEDodRgMEUdiCRj7twdnshjYbARACEcGZcAA5IvtopAVkD-YOBAwDiwgsflwCI8YGA4DAxYeiP73KpUBgD80OSDgEQ6toaHYmt217TuMyQjj2ABy0I4DBLSztM86zAMCDECmS7dt2gHAKIQA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very informative. But I noticed that when using this approach, it loses type support for `accessorKey`, which mean I can pass string value to `accessorKey`. In the long run it's fine but is there any way to enforce `accessorKey` should be at least the `keyof T` ?

Comment: Do you mean IntelliSense suggestions and autocomplete?  If so that seems to be outside of the scope of the question as asked (and also wasn't something you brought up earlier) so I don't know what to say.  That's a general design limitation of TypeScript, as described in [ms/TS#29729](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729).  There are techniques which can sometimes give you that effect but I haven't found anything that works for the example here.  How would you like to proceed here?

Comment: Yes I mean IntelliSense suggestions and autocomplete like you said. I have tried `K extends (keyof T | (string & {}))[]`  in the issue you mentioned but it doesn't work.
If it's a design limitation of TypeScript, I think I have to accept this trade off btw.